# Clonar select con diferente ID jQuery laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hola tengo un **select** el cual clono mediante jquery , la **clonación funciona perfecta** lo que necesito es poder cambiar el número de ID  **($num)**, el número  lo paso por controller con un valor inicial de 0 por lo tanto al crear la clonación debería ser de 1 y sumando dependiendo las veces que se presione el botón.

Código:

**Controller donde paso el valor iniciar de $num**

```
   return view('albaranes.crear-albaran-entrada',[

        'num' => 0,

    ]);
```

**Estructura Html del select, incluye blade de laravel**

```
<div id="div-materiales-{{$num}}" class="form-group">
            <label>Artículos</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <select class="form-control widthInput articulo-{{$num}}" id="articulo-{{$num}}" name="articulo-{{$num}}">
                    @foreach ($articulos as $articulo)

                    <option value="{{$articulo->id}}">{{ $articulo->codigo.". ".$articulo->descripcion }}</option>

                    @endforeach

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg" id="addMaterial" type="button">+ Añadir concepto</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( "#addMaterial" ).click(function() {

    var clone = $('#div-materiales-{{$num}}').clone('#articulo-{{$num}}');
     $('#div-materiales-{{$num}}').append(clone);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola ya he conseguido clonar  con ID diferente el select mediante el siguiente código :

```
    $( "#addMaterial" ).click(function() {

    $('#articulo-{{$num}}').clone().appendTo('#material-form').prop('id', 'articulo-' + 
            i);
        i++; 

    });
```